# autoremove hang on kernel removal

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 - `4.10.0-21-generic` and I was prompted to remove the old `4.10.0-19-generic` kernel however it's hanging removing the `linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic` part. See:

```
(Reading database ... 235316 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic (4.10.0-19.21) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic
```

Any advice? I tried rebooting and it still hangs removing this package which prevents any other installations.

Comment: What's the output of `dkms status -k 4.10.0-19-generic`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It may be the case that this just takes a long time and isn't hung.** I was having a similar problem, and finally after leaving it for a long time and I realized that it just is taking a really long time to finish and giving with no output. This gives the appearance of having hung because typically Linux and apt are both verbose and take roughly similar amounts of time to do things.

EDIT: upon further investigation, I believe that this is because `apt autoremove` is (unfortunately for us) smart enough to run `update-grub` each time it modifies a kernel, even if it is a redundant one. I realized this by running `sudo update-grub` manually afterwards, and sure enough, same huge waiting period.

For example, here is some output from my autoremove:

```
    Removing linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic (4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin

done
Removing linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic (4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.8.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
```

In my frustration I entered a few commands (*not* the right approach, but we have all been there...), just to see if things would respond. It did not. Going from the output "Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin" to "done" took about 15 minutes. No idea why it takes this long, but patience may help you, it did me!